# making Introduction Package online typo3 9.5.14

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have to mention that I am new to typo3 world and I am still learning. For this I have installed Introduction Package as described [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/In-depth/Distributions/Index.html) on my domain and now is my question what is the next step to make it visible when I call my page? This is not described in the tutorial I have mentioned.

when I go to page, it is empty, should I create new page and configure it? 
[image]

Comment: If you followed the installtion steps of the docs the site should be visible. Tell us about how you installed your TYPO3 instance, composer installation or symlinks or...

Comment: I have installed typo3 using the installation feature provided by hosting provider and then updated to new version 9.5.14 by copy paste. I havent't installed composer or symlinks

Comment: since one week and i still cant get started with typo3. does it make sense to use this cms if it is very complex and zero support?

Comment: Your picture shows me that the initial database import of the introduction distribution is not done. And we have a great support at our Slack channels, head to typo3.org and create an account. The community also is very active here at SO but main problem here is your question, you do not provide enough information to be able to help. You should also check the various logs to see what is going wrong. But yes, TYPO3 is a great CMS but also some kind complex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reinstalled the distribution 10 times, after multiple try I get confirmation that the installation of the distribution is done correctly.

Before it doesn't say that something went wrong it just show me that package you can see in screenshot. Strange cms

Comment: don't use answers as additional information to your question. edit the question! you may add a horizontal ruler to make edits visible.